# Does the spotify ios sdk allow users to stream spotify radio?

Tags: ios, spotify

Does the spotify ios sdk allow users to stream spotify radio?  Or does it only allow them to stream music if they subscribe to spotify premium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the iOS SDK will only play streaming audio for Premium subscribers.